# Google not indexing my site at all

Tags: google-search-console

I am working on a site right now and it does not appear in the google search results at all.

I have submitted the url at : https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url as well.

I have verified the ownership of my site using google's search console (I used the HTML file upload method). The verification was successful for the URL with `https` but it does not verify the URL with `http`.

At least it should show the website when search for it using the `site:` keyword. But it does not show anything.

Comment: How long have the site been up? Indexing takes time, usually 12-24 hrs the earliest.

Comment: The site has been up for more than 6 months. I first submitted the url 2 months ago and I added my site in webmasters tool for verification about a month ago.

Comment: I noticed it has another previous domain: `www.naps.vicniss.org.au`. Did you somehow setup a permanent redirection so search engines would know to update the links?

Comment: you can ask Google to reconsider your site. https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/reconsideration

Comment: @David I went to the reconsideration page and it just asks to check for Manual actions. On the manual actions page it says 'No manual webspam actions found.'